# Camera animation not working when map is touched - Mapbox v10

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I would like to perform a long press on the map and as soon as the long press is detected, move the center of the camera to the location of the long press.

`self.mapView.camera.ease` is not called as long as the finger is on the map.
It is only called when long press is ended.

How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

So in your code sample, instead of doing this:

mapView.camera = location

Try doing this:
mapView.animate(to: location)

and please let know, if it worked.

Comment: It's Mapbox v10, MapboxMaps.